# Vue.js - Error : Uncaught ReferenceError: getters is not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

When I run the project, it displays ReferenceError: getters is not defined as per following image:
[image]

**app.js** file:
[image]

**store.js** file:
[image]

What is problem causing this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you saved the file after commenting out getters lines? It shows unsaved statsus.

Comment: yes i am sure  because Unsaved changes are due to something else

Comment: Tyychange the import to => import store from './store/store'

Answer (score 0):

You should use **store.getters.variable_name** to retrieve state value.

Sample code for retrieving **accessToken**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    accessToken: null
  },
  getters: {
    accessToken: state => state.accessToken
  },
  actions: {
    doSomethingsHere({ commit }, somethingData) {
      console.log('accessToken: ' + store.getters.accessToken)
    }
  }
})

export default store
```